Disable arrow keys of keyboard on web page
I want to disable left and right arrows key of keyboard on a webpage, preventing the scroll to the previous or next slide.
I've this code:
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){  

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39 ) {
    alert('Not allowed');
     event.preventDefault();
    e.stop();
  }
    if (e.keyCode == 37 ) {
    alert('Not Allowed!');
    event.preventDefault(); 
    e.stop();
  } 
};
});

This is working: when I click on arrow key, the site shows alert, and then when I close it, its righty do anything (so I stay on the current slide).
The problem is when I disable the alerts: in this case, when I click on rigt or left key,the site goes to the next or to the previous slide, ignoring the block of the keyboard.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Give code how you implemented a slider please

You're passing e but suddenly you use event.preventDefault(); instead of e.preventDefault(); - Closing as typo. Also, instead of using e.keyCode use rather the more developer friendly e.key or e.code. Learn to use Developer Console to catch errors in your scripts.

the correct way to do this would be something like
document.addEventListener('keydown',keydown,true);    
function keydown(e){
    switch(e.key){
      case 'ArrowLeft'    :
      case 'ArrowRight'   :
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();  
    } // switch  
} // keydown

theres no need to wait for the document to be ready or anything you can just run it straight away


var $ = sel = >document.querySelector(sel);
var adj = (sel, prop, v) = >{
    var node = $(sel);
    var value = node.style[prop];
    value = value || 0;
    value = parseInt(value) + v;
    node.style[prop] = value + 'px';
  }

  document.addEventListener('keydown', keydown, true);

  function keydown(e) {
    if ($('#chk').checked == false) return;
    switch (e.key) {
    case 'ArrowLeft':
    case 'ArrowRight':
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    } //switch
  } //keydown
  body {
  margin:25px
}
#box {
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  background:lightblue
}
#slider {
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:100%;
  background:lightgreen;
  margin:2
}
#chk-root {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin:10px 0;
}
input {
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:0
  10px
}
label {
  font-size:20px;
  cursor:pointer
}
<div>
  click blue box then arrows to slide
</div>
<div id=chk-root>
  <label for=chk>
    enabled
  </label>
  <input id=chk type=checkbox>
</div>
<div id=box tabindex=-1>
  <div id=slider>
    </slider>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $('#box').onkeydown = e = >{
    if (e.key == 'ArrowLeft') adj('#slider', 'left', -5);
    if (e.key == 'ArrowRight') adj('#slider', 'left', 5);
  };
</script>




It blocks anything

im not exactly sure what youre looking for, i thought thats what you wanted, do you want to click your slider then only sometimes disable the keys?

Avoid using stopImmediatePropagation and stopPropagation

@Roko, i dont understand what you mean
